# MySQL loop for total score each week

Tags: mysql

The following statement outputs the `userName` and `week1Score`. I would like it to loop through 17 times, to get the score for each of the 17 weeks.

```
SELECT userName, (totalWins+(totalPushs*.5)) AS week1Score FROM (
    SELECT *, SUM(win) AS totalWins, SUM(lost) AS totalLost, SUM(push) AS totalPushs FROM (
        SELECT *, (finalResult = 'win') AS win, (finalResult = 'loss') AS lost, (finalResult = 'push') AS push FROM (
            SELECT userName, IF (pickID=visitorID, visitorResult, homeResult) AS finalResult
            FROM table_users
            JOIN table_picks
            ON table_users.userID = table_picks.userID
            JOIN table_schedule
            ON table_picks.gameID = table_schedule.gameID
            WHERE weekNum = 1
        ) x
    ) x GROUP BY userName
) x ORDER BY userName
```

The above statement outputs the following.

```
+-----------------------+
| userName | week1Score |
+-----------------------+
```

I would like it to loop through 17 times to to output the following.

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| userName | week1Score | week2Score | week3Score | week4Score | week... |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How would I use MySQL loop to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is a bit complex. However, there's a better approach: a Pivot Query.

MySQL does not have a "pivot"  instruction, but an expression can be built to get the output you need.

I'll build a temp table to make things a bit easier to read (I am using user variables to make things a bit clearer):

```
-- This first table will compute the score
drop table if exists temp_step01;
create temporary table temp_step01
select userId
     , userName
     , weekNum
     , @finalResult := if(pickId=visitorId, visitorResult, homeResult) as finalResult
     , @w := @finalResult = 'win' as win
     , @l := @finalResult = 'loss' as lost
     , @p := @finalResult = 'push' as push
     , @w + (@p * 0.5) as score
from
    table_users as tu
    join table_picks as tp on tu.userId = tp.userId
    join table_schedule as ts on tp.gameId = ts.gameId;
alter table temp_step01
    add index uid(userId),
    add index wn(weekNum);
```

Now, the fun part: build the pivot table

```
-- First, build the expression for each column
select 
    group_concat(
      concat(
        'sum(case weekNum when ', weekNum, ' then score end) as week', weekNum, 'score'
      )
    )
into @sql
from (select distinct weekNum from temp_step01) as a;
-- Then, create a complete SELECT statement
set @sql = concat('select userId, userName, ', @sql, ' from temp_step01 group by userId');
-- OPTIONAL: Check that the sql statement is well written:
select @sql;
-- Now, prepare a statement, and execute it
prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
-- When you're done, don't forget to deallocate the statement
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

A bit laborious, but I think this will give you what you need. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm getting a `SQL syntax error near '@sql, ' from temp_step01 group by userId')'`

Comment: This is the result I get, column name `@sql` value `select userId, userName, sum(case weekNum when 1 t...` not sure if thats what it's suppose to be but that is not what I was looking for.

Comment: continue with the following steps: prepare the statement and execute it (did you notice that I wrote "OPTIONAL" above "select @sql"? that is meant for you to read the full sql statement before it's executed)

Comment: @user2759965 The `@sql` variable holds the query needed to get what you need. But you need to execute it. Execute `prepare stmt from @sql; execute stmt;` to get your result... and when you're done with it, `deallocate prepare stmt;`  will clean up the prepared statement.